# Wikipedia (API) "List_of" page contents - Parse to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing, wikipedia-api

My question is simple: how can I return a JSON structure for all list items on any wikipedia page that begins with "List of"? If that is not feasible through Wiki API, what is best way to parse wiki HTML/ XML to what I need? (note- parsing does not have to be perfect)

There is roughly 225,000 of these pages and they mostly seem to be one of these 4 styles. For example:
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Trek%3A_The_Next_Generation_episodes    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_car_brands    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Presidents_of_the_United_States    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FIFA_World_Cup_goalscorers

specifically I would like something I can use, like:

```
Star Trek: Next Generation episodes->
  season 1-> 
    Encounter at Farpoint 
    Encounter at Farpoint 
    The Naked Now 
    ... 
  season 2->
    The Child
    Where Silence Has Lease
    Elementary, Dear Data 
    ...
  ...
...
```

The closest solutions I have come up with so far are Axios Wikipedia API parse calls that I would need to run for each section. Furthermore, despite setting JSON parameter I still receive list items as xml or HTML for "text" property of returned JSON. Parsing this becomes difficult for all the different page types. Any suggesting with how to parse multiple wiki type lists items would be helpful if JSON return is not possible.

Any suggestions to accomplish my goal? I am using VUE.js with nodejs.

- Maybe their is a library that could help?
- Maybe a get request on URL to get full html dump would work better?
- Maybe their is a wikidump of just list pages that I could parse to firestore?

---

Answer (score 1):

The concept of wiki data solves this issue, however it is still no where near maturity level to provide much value. In maybe 3-5 years it could avoid this problem all together.

At this time the quick and dirty way to answer this question is just grabbing all the links on a given wikipedia page through api, then either programmatically filter or have user do so. This works because the vast majority of star trek episodes, presidents, and car brands on a given list will be linked to their individual wikipedia pages.

I used the following API query to get all links on a wikipedia page (using pageid)

```
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
      params: {
        action: 'query',
        format: 'json',
        prop: 'pageterms|pageimages',
        origin: '*',
        generator: 'links',
        gpllimit: '500',
        redirects: 'true',
        pageids: pageidIn,
        piprop: 'thumbnail',
        formatversion: 2
      }
```

Then save off `response.data.query.pages[i].terms.description` and `response.data.query.pages[i].title` to class object of results

Then I added an additional search field for user to filter their prior results. If they enter "episode" it will get me what I need since the word "episode" is typically in the response.data.query.pages[i].terms.description field of the page.

Only drawback is this solution wont return list results that don't have their own wiki page. But for the sake of simplicity, I will accept that.